How to replace a node when using rapidxml
Given 2 XML documents:
Document 1:
<A>
   ...
   <B>..<B>
   <include>reference/to/document2</include>
   <C>..</C>
   ...
</A>

Document 2:
<X>
   <Y>..<Y>
   <Z>..</Z>
</X>

I need to replace <include> node in document 1 with the content of document 2. The final document should be:
<A>
   ...
   <B>..<B>
   <X>
       <Y>..<Y>
       <Z>..</Z>
   </X>
   <C>..</C>
   ...
</A>

Is it possible to do it with rapidxml? It should be straight forward to add it to the bottom. But I could not figure out yet how to replace a node (or insert after the specific node N and then remove node N).
